# How to convert float strings to integer strings?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of float numbers (appear as strings) and NaN values.

```
import numpy as np
mylist = ['1.0', '0.0', np.nan, 'a']
```

I need to convert float string values into integer string values, while ignoring the rest of records:

```
mylist = ['1', '0', np.nan, 'a']
```

How can I do it?

I wrote the following code, but I don't know how to handle the exceptions `np.nan`, `a`, etc.

```
mylist2 = []
for i in mylist:
   mylist2.append(str(int(float(n))))
```

Comment: Well, what do you want to happen for NaN or infinity, or non-integer strings?

Comment: What is this for? Seems slightly odd, no?

Comment: @kaya3 He said he want to ignore rest of the record.

Comment: But what does "ignore" mean? Leave them as is, remove them, something else?

Comment: How did you **get** the data? Can you fix it before you create the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a map that calls a function to convert them to ints:

````
def to_int(x):
    try:
        x = str(int(float(x)))
    except:
        pass
    return x

np.array(list(map(to_int, mylist)), dtype=object)                                                                                                                                  
# array(['1', '0', nan, 'a'], dtype=object)```
````

Answer (score 0):

Although there are different ways to achieve this. but let's go your way.
This might help.

```
 mylist2 = []
    for i in mylist:
        try:
            mylist2.append(str(int(float(n))))
        except:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to just use the original values when they are not numeric strings that can be converted to integers, you can write a helper function to try doing the conversion, and return the original value if an exception is raised.

```py
def try_int(s):
    try:
        return str(int(float(s)))
    except:
        return s

mylist2 = [try_int(s) for s in mylist]
```

Be aware that the conversion from a float string to an int can sometimes make the strings much longer; for example, the string `'9e200'` will be converted to an integer string with 201 digits.